# Instagram Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication not available?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have searched google and I have seen a lot of related questions and answers on this issue but none of them are clear.

I am trying to use Instagram API and as far as I understand, since I am building a client-side app (VueJS) is not a good idea to store the client_secret on the client.

Based on the Instagram Documentation [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) it seems that there was a way to use implicit authentication.

The problem is that after Facebook took over Instagram and launched the [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) it seems that there is no way to use implicit authentication.

Does anyone have any information regarding this? The only solution is to build a server-side app for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using an access token.
This token can be generated and has to be refreshed at least every 60 days using a `GET` request and your app-secret.
This can either be done automatically, in that case with a server side application or by hand.
Source: [facebook developer guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens)

If it helps I created a snippet for vue after wasting the better half of an afternoon on this matter.
You can find it here: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1957175